# Grep for <?php after blank line

Tags: regex, linux, unix, grep, pcre

How can I `grep` *(or something similar)* after files which has a blank line followed by `<?php`?

I tried without success:

```
grep -irn '(?<=.\r)\r<?php' *
```

I read in some posts that grep doesn't seem to support multiline and [pcregrep](http://www.pcre.org/) should be used instead.
How can I `pcregrep` for `<?php` after a blank line?

Comment: ok, i saw in some posts that grep doesn't seem to support multiline and one should use pcregrep instead http://www.pcre.org/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do what you want:

```
pcregrep -rinM '^\n<\?php' .
```